# Can you allow employers to be excluded from Careers search?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Example: In Seattle, the returns are greatly dominated by Amazon and I'd personally rather not work for them.

Comment: Curious why you would not want to work for them (just wondering if you've worked there before)?  I just got contacted by them for a second interview.

Comment: Suffice it to say there are good reasons why they do so much out-of-area recruiting.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean?  Do you mean they recruit outside of seattle because half of seattle has worked for them?  Is it just not a good place to work?

Comment: Not much fun in Stalingrad, to quote the Monty Python sketch.

Comment: Here's another use case: A user may not want to see job postings from the company that just laid them off.

Answer (score 10):

I was about to say "suck it up and just ignore them" but  I kinda see your point when doing a 
search in Seattle.

Maybe Careers could allow negative keywords like `-Amazon` in the "what" section? If those are then applied to the company name, this could be implemented without having to actually add a "exclude employer" feature. Of course, it would have to be made discoverable somehow.

Comment: I'd prefer the exclusion of specific employers. "-Name" might exclude things you don't want to exclude.

Answer (score 7):

We’ve added a negative search, per Pekka’s suggestion. Here is a link for [non-Amazon jobs near Seattle](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=-amazon&location=seattle) – note the syntax.

It’s a negative *keyword* search, so it doesn’t strictly look at employers. If a job listing mentions Amazon (say in the context of AWS), then it’ll likely be excluded as well.

Comment: S.L.Barth's counter-point to my suggestion has merit, but I guess this is a step in the right direction, and helps in extreme situations like the one the OP is in!

Comment: From 104 down to 40, which is a great help in filtering out the chaff!

Comment: Is there a negative search by location? Pretty please I need this. I'm looking for a job that is NOT in the US and it's a lot more _chaff_. It looks like half the jobs come out of there. I literally go through each of the many pages sifting through the results.

Comment: Seems like putting `-usa` into what worked.

Comment: This worked for a long time, but it recently became broken. '0 job for "-amazon" near Seattle, WA'